# Help with Grub and two Windows disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a dual boot tower with 19.10 and Windows 10.
The disks in the system are one NVMe, one SSD and three SATA spinning disks. The NVMe contains Windows 10. It is cloned to one of the SATA disks using Macrium while running Windows. The SSD is just extra space for Windows. Macrium says a cloned disk gets a different ID.

The problem I have is that when update-grub is run, the NVMe disks gets the same UUID as its clone, so when I select it from the Grub menu, it boots into the clone. I can't figure out how to identify the NVMe device in grub.cfg in order to boot into it.

Maybe a better way to pose this is, I can't figure out how to get os-prober to pick the NVMe correctly. I don't know how osprober works in grub.cfg, but it seems off that both disks get the same ID in the string.

Here's the relevant part of grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p3)" --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-8068-6E17' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8068-6E17
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8068-6E17
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb3)" --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-8068-6E17' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd1,gpt3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3 8068-6E17
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8068-6E17
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

How do I get this to be configured correctly? Thanks!

Comment: clone is not meant to be mounted except to restore or replace broken system. This is then duplcated: `set=root 8068-6E17` and system cannot tell them apart. Duplicate UUID/GUID not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that is what is happening.

Okay, my solution was to clone the Windows disk to an external USB disk (doing so in Windows) and then reformatting the internal clone disk. update-grub then does not find it.

The disk ID didn't change now that there is one of them in the grub.cfg.

So, I think it would work to manually delete part of grub.cfg for the clone, too. The IDs of the two disks apparently really are the same, and grub happened to boot the clone, so removing it should get it to boot the right Windows disk.